# SQL Server temp table cannot be created but doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor, temp-tables

Forgive me I rarely work with large SQL Server stored procedures but I am having quite the issue with this following stored procedure.

Basically I am trying to take a manually run query that includes unions and place it into a stored procedure with a cursor and return the results into a temp table. However, I am receiving an error that the temp table cannot be created because it "already exists" (which I have run a check to see if it does exist, which It does not) or I do not have permission (which I do because I am logged in as the SQL admin). What on earth am I doing wrong?

I ran the follow query to see if it does exist within both tempdb and where the stored procedure is being create and it returns the else statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('IPAM..#tempschedule') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT '#temp exists!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT '#temp does not exist!'
END
```

Here is the stored procedure that I am trying to ALTER:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE lakearrowhead_schedule_python
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempschedule') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tempschedule;
    END;

    CREATE TABLE #tempschedule
    (
        ProgramID INT,
        ItemID INT,
        Day SMALLINT,
        [Date] DATE,
        [Begin TIME] VARCHAR(15),
        [End TIME] VARCHAR(15),
        TIMESLOT NVARCHAR(11),
        SLOTTYPE INT,
        SlotTypeDescription NVARCHAR(64),
        SLOTINFO INT,
        SlotInfoDescription NVARCHAR(500),
        TalkID INT,
        Talk NVARCHAR(50),
        FIRSTNAME NVARCHAR(20),
        LASTNAME NVARCHAR(50),
        INSTITUTION NVARCHAR(150),
        AUTHORLINE NVARCHAR(384),
        TITLE NVARCHAR(256),
        Abstract VARCHAR(1),
        [LOCATION] INT,
        ADDENDUM TEXT,
        EventName NVARCHAR(256)
    );

    DECLARE @pid INT;

    DECLARE PROGRAM_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT TOP 3 WebEvents.EventID
        FROM WebEvents
        INNER JOIN dbo.WebPrograms ON dbo.WebEvents.EventID = dbo.WebPrograms.ProgramID
        WHERE EventLocation = 1004
          AND (eventstartdate >= GETDATE())
        ORDER BY 
            eventstartdate, ProgramCode;

    OPEN PROGRAM_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM PROGRAM_cursor INTO @pid;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        INTO #tempschedule
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                 WS.ProgramID ,
                 WS.ItemID ,
                 WS.Day ,
                 CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, WS.Day - 1, WE.eventstartdate))
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'Sun'
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'Mon'
                     WHEN 3 THEN 'Tue'
                     WHEN 4 THEN 'Wed'
                     WHEN 5 THEN 'Thu'
                     WHEN 6 THEN 'Fri'
                     WHEN 7 THEN 'Sat'
                     ELSE 'N/A'
                 END + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY, WS.Day - 1, WE.eventstartdate), 101) AS Date,
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(TIME, SUBSTRING(WS.TimeSlot, 0, 6)), 100) AS 'Begin TIME',
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(TIME, SUBSTRING(WS.TimeSlot, 7, 6)), 100) AS 'End TIME',
                 WS.TimeSlot,
                 WS.SlotType,
                 WSSTC.Description AS SlotTypeDescription,
                 WS.SlotInfo,
                 WSSIC.Description AS SlotInfoDescription,
                 ISNULL(WSI.TalkID, 0) AS TalkID,
                 LEFT(WPI.FirstName, 10) + ' '
                     + LEFT(WPI.LastName, 10) + ' ('
                     + LEFT(WEA.institution, 10) + ')' + ' - '
                     + LEFT(WSI.Title, 10) + '...'
                     + RIGHT(WSI.Title, 10) AS Talk,
                 WPI.FirstName,
                 WPI.LastName,
                 WEA.institution,
                 WSI.AuthorLine,
                 WSI.Title,
                 LEFT(WSI.Abstract, 1) AS Abstract,
                 WS.Location,
                 WS.Addendum,
                 WE.EventName
             FROM   
                 dbo.WebSpeakerInfo WSI
             INNER JOIN 
                 dbo.WebPersonalInfo WPI ON WSI.UserID = WPI.UserID
             INNER JOIN 
                 dbo.webeventaffiliation WEA ON WPI.UserID = WEA.userid
                                             AND WEA.eventid = @pid
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
                 dbo.WebScheduleSlotTypeCodes WSSTC 
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
                 dbo.WebSchedules WS ON WSSTC.SlotType = WS.SlotType 
                 ON WSI.TalkID = WS.TalkID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                 dbo.WebScheduleSlotInfoCodes WSSIC ON WS.SlotInfo = WSSIC.SlotInfo
             INNER JOIN 
                 dbo.WebEvents WE ON WE.EventID = @pid
             WHERE  
                 WS.ProgramID = @pid
                 AND WS.SlotType <> 6 ) AS x
            ORDER BY 
                 Day, TimeSlot;

        FETCH NEXT FROM PROGRAM_cursor INTO @pid;
    END;

    CLOSE PROGRAM_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE PROGRAM_cursor;

    SELECT *
    FROM #tempschedule;

    DROP TABLE #tempschedule;
```

Comment: It looks like your check statement is looking at a different database than tempdb, or am I missing something?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I tried the tempdb but also checked the database this procedure goes into (IPAM)  just in case the server put it in there for some strange reason. It is stuck somewhere in memory out in SQL lala land, as I cannot find it anywere

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I don't remember the specifics of the situation but I've run into something similar a few times. I just ran the drop table by itself without an if statement, then reran everything and it usually works. Might try that.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock SQL Server 2017, and lol I also tried just dropping the table without any checks or anything and still didn't work.

Comment: Well unrelated to actually solving your problem, but if you are in 2017 I would switch to DIE statements. They were introduced in 2016 and making dropping tables,views,constraints,stored procs, etc. a lot easier. Just do DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempschedule

Comment: One last thought, I've also gotten burned by having queries connected with one to our dev server and one to the prod server and run into similar issues where I swear it doesn't exist in query A, but then it's definitely there in query B. Doubt that's your problem but maybe.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `ALTER` statement, you are turning the stored procedure into this statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE lakearrowhead_schedule_python
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempschedule') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #tempschedule;
        END;
```

The rest of the statements are just executed after the `ALTER`.

Moral of the story?  *Always* use `BEGIN`/`END` blocks for stored procedures, functions, and trigger.

I should note that temporary tables are deleted automatically when the stored procedure ends.  You can be even more certain by using a table variable.  These are both deleted and out-of-scope.  So, explicitly deleting temporary tables is not necessary within the body of a stored procedure.

Comment: Ok that makes sense,  so by placing a BEGIN right after the "AS" and an END after the "DROP TABLE #tempschedule;" the error should disappear correct? Or is there more to my issue than just that? I added the BGIN and END but still getting the errors
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure lakearrowhead_schedule_python, Line 49 [Batch Start Line 0]
There is already an object named '#tempschedule' in the database.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure lakearrowhead_schedule_python, Line 111 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Yeah I kind of thought it was strange that I would have to drop the temp table at the end of the stored procedure.

Comment: I even deleted the SP and tried to do a Create instead of an Alter and I still get the errors. LOL this is frustrating. I might have to just go an alternate route, but passing in the 3 ID's from my web app and run the original Union query.